# Deploying Office Solutions Without Certificate

Tags: c#, excel, registry, vsto, clickonce

I am attempting to distribute a VSTO Excel Add-in without a signed certificate and I am running into issues with some users not receiving the Click Once trust prompt.

Note that the VSTO is being installed from `c:\Users\...`

[image]

I followed the steps here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-configure-the-clickonce-trust-prompt-behavior?view=vs-2017

to enable the Click Once trust prompt but they are still receiving the prompt above without the option to install the add-in.

Is there a best practice method for deploying a solution without signing?

Comment: XY problem.  Why don't you just sign it?

Comment: This Add-in is only for a few users, so if possible I would like to avoid spending $200-$300 to purchase a certificate from a Certificate Authority. Is there any other way to certify my Add-in so that these users are able to install?

Comment: Sure, you don't need to buy one.   Our VSTO solution was only going to be used internally by management and they were content with DEV-level certificate.  They will just get a notice saying that the publisher can't be certified.  It just required training (or an email) to tell them to just click install anyway.  However, it was hosted on the intranet so you might have different issues if hosted on the Internet.

Comment: I just noticed that the error is about _location_ and that the path is essentially local with `c:\users\...`.  What is the full path?  Did you copy it there over the LAN?  Is the path in your user's `Downloads`?